# django allauth url for google login

Tags: django-allauth

I have a sign-in template and I want to add an icon that users can click to go to the google authentication process. I have Django allauth, but how can I get the right url for the google flow?

I tried `<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">` but it sends the user to the login page while I want to send them straight to `accounts/google/login/` (ideally generating the url using django and not harcoding it. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this instead :

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login with Google</a>
```

Comment: django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 14: 'provider_login_url', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: I think it's considering it as a templetag

Comment: {% load socialaccount %} added this one and it worked! GThanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** :

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}">Google</a>
```

**Context** :

Use the provider_login_url tag to generate provider specific login URLs:

```
{% load socialaccount %}

<a href="{% provider_login_url "openid" openid="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" next="/success/url/" %}">Google</a>
<a href="{% provider_login_url "twitter" %}">Twitter</a>
```

Here, you can pass along an optional process parameter that indicates how to process the social login. You can choose between login and connect:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "twitter" process="connect" %}">Connect a Twitter account</a>
```

Furthermore, you can pass along an action parameter with value reauthenticate to indicate that you want the user to be re-prompted for authentication even if they already signed in before. For now, this is supported by Facebook, Google and Twitter only.

For Javascript based logins (e.g. when you enable the Facebook JS SDK), you will need to make sure that the required Javascript is loaded. The following tag loads all scripts for the enabled providers:

```
{% providers_media_js %}
```

For easy access to the social accounts for a user use:

```
{% get_social_accounts user as accounts %}
```

Then:

```
{{accounts.twitter}} -- a list of connected Twitter accounts
{{accounts.twitter.0}} -- the first Twitter account
{% if accounts %} -- if there is at least one social account
```

Finally, social authentication providers configured for the current site can be retrieved via:

```
{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
```

source : https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/socialaccount/templates.html